# beta regression vs. linear regression for strictly bounded outcome variable [0,1]

Tags: statistics, regression, linear-regression, logistic-regression

So I am trying to explain my strictly bounded variable (percentage) with some predictors - categorical as well as numerical. I have read quite a bit about the topic, but I am still confused about some of the arguments. The purpose of my regression is explaining, not predicting.

**What are the consequences of running a linear regression on a strictly bounded outcome variable?**

Answer (score 2):

A linear regression does not have a bounded output. It's a linear transformation of the input, so if the input is twice as large, the output will be twice as large. That way, it will always be possible to find an input that exceeds the boundaries of the output.

You can apply a sigmoid function to the output of the linear regression (this is called "logistic regression"), but this will model a binary variable and give you the probability of the variable being 1. In your case, your variable isn't binary, it can have any value between 0 and 1. For that problem, you need to apply a beta regression, which will give you a bounded output between 0 and 1.

Comment: linear regression with a sigmoidal function would be beta regression, right? But what if i am not interested in making any predictions? I just want to know which predicotrs are wignificant and which are not. Would the estimation of stardard error be affected if i run the linear regression on a bounded outcome variable ?

Comment: No, a linear regression with a sigmoid is called logistic regression. Google for beta regression vs logistic regression to find many discussions of the differences. It comes down this: Logistic regression can be used to model a binary variable where the regression value gives the probability of the variable being one. Beta regression can be used to model a continuous variable from 0 to 1 using any probability distribution between those values. I have realized my answer wasn't right, so I updated it.